# Iterating through many CSV files in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have many CSV files that are my datapoint files, they are different combinations of my test subjects.
[image]

I have some code that runs one CSV at a time, but I have to comment/uncomment when I want my code the analyse the next CSV.

Is there any good looping techniques that I can apply such that the processing/iteration is automatic for all my CSVs?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, create list of filenames and then loop by it:

```
files = ['BenNIC O.csv','BenQQ O.csv']

for file in files:
     df = pd.read_csv(file)
     #processing
```